# Programmatically import a feed

Tags: 7, rules, feeds

I can successfully import remote content using the Feeds module by manually clicking on the *Import* button. I need to execute the import process from code, either from a module or executing PHP code from the Rules module.

I have tried the following code in a custom module.

```
function imports_cron_cron(){
  drupal_set_message('Import-CRON responding to cron execution! ...');
  $importer_id = 'publications_import';
  $url = "http://xml/url";
  $feeds_source = feeds_source($importer_id);
  $feeds_config = $feeds_source->getConfigFor($feeds_source->importer->fetcher);
  $feeds_config['source'] = $url;
  $feeds_source->setConfigFor($feeds_source->importer->fetcher, $feeds_config);
  $feeds_source->save();
  $feeds_source->startImport();

  drupal_set_message(' .... ENDING IMPORTS-CRON CALL!');
}
```

Both the `drupal_set_message()` calls are successfully executed, but no node is imported.

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 13):

Your code seems to be OK. I use some similar code in one of my projects (this a csv importer, similar concept):

```
function custom_function($importer_id, $csvfile_path) {
  // Load the Feeds Source object.
  $source = feeds_source($importer_id);
  // Load the source fetcher config.
  $fetcher_config = $source->getConfigFor($source->importer->fetcher);
  $fetcher_config['source'] = $csvfile_path;
  $source->setConfigFor($source->importer->fetcher, $fetcher_config);
  $source->save();
  $source->startImport();
}
```

Make sure that you are using the foreground configuration, this way the batch process could be be executed "inside" drupal with showing the progress bar. Or you can force it:

```
// Tweak the importer configuration, to enable "Process in the background".
$config = array(
  'process_in_background' => TRUE,
);
$source->importer->addConfig($config);

// Execute the import.
```

Another approach could be to schedule it

```
// Schedule the import, and make sure importer is scheduled, too.
$source->schedule();
$source->importer->schedule();
```

[This is a good article about feeds importer](http://nodesforbreakfast.com/article/2012/09/23/programmatically-execute-feeds-importer-drupal-7)

Answer (score 1):

Ive seen lots about this. 
Heres my take , I want to be able to do this from the command line, and be able to do it from an install profile.

so taking hints from previous answers, and from the [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/622700) [Ive](https://www.drupal.org/node/1151914) [seen](https://drupalcommerce.org/discussions/1072/how-can-i-execute-commerce-feeds-imports-programmatically) / found, Ive come to the realisation that

dont use the batch api for this *unless*

a) you're doing this from the form api (a user clicks)

or

b) 
you're writing a [drush command](https://www.drupal.org/node/873132).

so this is what Ive got working in an module install

```
function load_data(){

// Files to import in specific order.
  $files = array(
    'challenge_importer' => 'data/challenges.csv',
);

$file_location_base = drupal_get_path('module', 'challenge');
foreach ($files as $feed => $file) {

$feedSource = feeds_source($feed);
// Set the file name to import
$filename = $file_location_base.'/' . $file;
if (!file_destination($filename, FILE_EXISTS_ERROR)) {
  $config = $feedSource->getConfig();
  $config['FeedsFileFetcher']['source'] = $filename;
  $feedSource->setConfig($config);
  $feedSource->save();
    while (FEEDS_BATCH_COMPLETE != $feedSource->import());
    }
  }
}
```

where

- challenge_importer is a feeds importer,
- challenge is the module.
- data is stored in module/data

  and with this structure you can have multiple files imported in a defined order.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to do something more like

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = 'feed';
$node->title = 'My feed';
$node->feeds['FeedsHTTPFetcher']['source'] = 'http://example.com/rss.xml';
node_save($node);
```

You should take a look at https://drupal.org/node/622700 (Programmatic operations).

Comment: Thank you Steven but I am looking for a stand-alone form solution rather than a node based solution.

Comment: If that's what you are looking for I believe what you are trying to do should work. Try adding some `watchdog` functions on variables to see what the variables contain.